# GCD of a series of integers with integer coefficients

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

If $a,b,c,d,$... be a series of integers whose GCD is $g$, show that integers
(positive or negative) $A, B , C, D$ can be found such that

$$g = Aa + Bb + Cc + Dd + ...$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the infinite sum to make sense, we need to make sure that only finitely many terms are nonzero. So we need that a finite subset of $S=\{a,b,c,\ldots\}$ has $\gcd$ equal to $g$.

You may prove this by looking at prime factorisation: for each prime $p$ dividing $g$ there is a number $x_p$ in $S$ with $\nu_p(g)=\nu_p(x_p)$. Then the finite subset $\{x_p:p\mid g\}$ will do.

A more fancy way uses some algebra: $\mathbb Z$ is a UFD and thus satisfies [ACCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascending_chain_condition_on_principal_ideals). So the sequence $(a),(a)+(b),(a)+(b)+(c),\ldots$ stabilizes; say the result is $(h)$. Then $h\mid a,b,c,\ldots$ and is the largest such number, so $h=g$. Because the sequence stabilizes, $g$ is the $\gcd$ of a finite subset of $S$.